# Can I use Granulated sugar instead of White sugar?

Tags: baking, cake, chocolate, sugar

I'm making a dark chocolate cake, it calls for white sugar but I have an unopened bag of granulated suagr at home. Can I use that instead to save some money or will I have to buy white sugar?

Comment: Should be the same stuff, unless there's a translation problem hidden in the question: http://www.thekitchn.com/a-complete-visual-guide-to-sugar-ingredient-intelligence-213715

Comment: Granulated only describes the size of the crystals, versus powdered, caster, fine etc, not the type or colour. You can have granulated brown or other colours.

Comment: Reading between the lines do you maybe mean brown sugar?

Comment: @user110084 I wonder if the definition varies by country. I checked mine and the white sugar says granulated (although I know there are castor and

Comment: @Jude, is there even a formal set of definitions for sugar you know of? I have never really thought about it until now. Particle sizes do vary a lot even for common granulated between countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sugar you have is actually coarser than "normal" white sugar (say, crystals are more than a mm in size):

If the recipe calls for dissolving the sugar (eg by vigorously stirring it into the wet ingredients), there is no difference at all - just make sure you dissolve it fully, coarser sugar takes more time/work to dissolve.

If the recipe calls for mixing the sugar with the fat or with dry ingredients first, sugar grain size makes a difference in texture - which will likely not ruin the cake though. If you want to be sure, you can make the sugar finer using any of a (dry!!!) blender, coffee grinder, food processor, mortar and pestle...